# Equation relating the specific index of a value in an array and the size of the array MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to come up with an equation that relates the index of a value within a 3D array, to the index of the same array but reshaped into a column vector.

Consider the following.

```
A = randi([1,10],3,2,2);
A2 = reshape(A,3*2*2,1);
```

`A` and `A2` have the same number of elements, but the arrangement of the elements is different for each array. If I lay out a possible example for `A` and `A2` here it is clear geometrically how each index lines up.

```
A(:,:,1) = [9 10; 10 7;  2  1]
A(:,:,2) = [3 10;  6 2; 10 10]

A2 = [9; 10; 2; 10; 7; 1; 3; 6; 10; 10; 2; 10]
```

Let's say `n=1:1:3*2*2`, this is an array that is the same length as `A2` and numbers each of the elements. The value of `A(2,2,2)=2` and has indices `[i,j,k]=[2,2,2]`. I would like to have an equation relating i, j, k, and n.

I've looked into the built-in functions `ind2sub` and `sub2ind` but it seems that I inadvertently shaped my i, j, and k coordinates (which correspond with real x, y, and z points) differently than how MatLab does. This makes it difficult for me to change everything now, and is why I need an equation.

Comment: Thank you I meant a 12x1, I will correct this.

Comment: @Wolfie I explained what I mean regarding the coordinates, what exactly do you not understand? I don't think it has any bearing on answering the question.

Comment: I was just trying to advise you of some best practise... if you were going by convention then it sounds like `ind2sub` and `sub2ind` would be your answer, no? You could easily reverse engineer this by starting with the 1D vector, and using values equal to the indices rather than random numbers.

Comment: No because I don't have time to do that.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rahnema1 I have updated the question.

Comment: @rahnema1 Why? That has no bearing on the answer. I have an M x N x P array, and I reshape it into a M*N*P x 1 array. I would like to relate the indices of the first array to the indices of the second. The only reason that information was provided was to show the readers that I had looked into the available options and that I don't think they will work in my case.

Comment: I mean that why you don't want to use sub2ind and ind2sub?

Comment: @rahnema1 I'm sorry but that was explained, and others (see answer below) were able to understand it fine.

Comment: Also, your accepted answer replicates what `sub2ind` does.

Comment: The reason I cannot use `sub2ind` is not relevant. I have tried to explain why, but the question was answered and I have successfully tested them for my purposes.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I was not aware of that. I had tried using `sub2ind` on smaller arrays formatted in the same way as I have done and was not receiving accurate results. That could be due to a number of factors.

Comment: With your matrices above, `A(i,j,k) == A2(sub2ind(size(A),i,j,k))`. Please define "not accurate". You are not setting up these matrices in any strange way. It is not possible to set up matrices to change indexing. `reshape` never changes the layout of elements in memory, and therefore doesn't change linear indexing. The same linear index will always point at the same element, no matter how you reshape the matrix.

Comment: Not accurate means returning incorrect results in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion between 3D index and linear (1D) index is given by:

```
n=i+(j-1)*M + (k-1)*M*N
```

The reverse can be obtained recursively as:

```
k = floor((n-1)/(M*N)) +1 
n = n - (k-1)*M*N
j = floor((n-1)/M) + 1
i = n - (j-1)*M
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it will give you what you are expeccting.

Comment: The first part works great. I tested out the second part and it doesn't seem to be working. Since I'm not working with random arrays, and I know the exact values of each element, and that they are not repeated, I can find i, j, and k if I only know n that way. But it would be good to have something more general for when that is not the case.

I think I can accept your answer now. But if you have time to figure out the second half that would be great.

Comment: This is exactly what `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` compute.

Comment: @CrisLuengo as I said above, I'm not sure why when I was using `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` on my machine why I was receiving different results. I was under the impression that this was due to the way I setup my arrays, since I had dealt with that in the past in other situations.

Comment: Actually, this is not exactly the same, because it's wrong... There is an `n=n-1` missing at the top of the second block of code. The computations assume a 0-based linear index.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion my misunderstanding of how `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` work caused. I think I understand it better now, which will help in the future.